# Angular5 + HttpClient + Observable + HTTP PUT + 204 NO CONTENT

Tags: angular5

I have a webapi , which has HTTP PUT method with return result "204 No content" (if success). I try to use Angular5 + HttpClient + Observable to update data.
My code is :

```
updateUser(user): Observable<object> {
var putUrl = this.userURL + "/" + user.id;
var result = this.http.put(putUrl, user).pipe(
  catchError(this.handleError)
);
return result;}


private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
      console.error('An error occurred:', error.error.message);
    } else {
      // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
      // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong,
      console.error(
        `Backend returned code ${error.status}, ` +
        `body was: ${error.error}`);
    }
    // return an observable with a user-facing error message
    return _throw(
      'Something bad happened; please try again later.');
  };
```

I clicked update button and there are no request to server in network tab, there are no console error. Where is am I wrong ?

**UPDATE** I so stupid, I'm sorry. I should subscibe() to the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid question, I was hurry.
Should : this.userService.updateUser(user).subscribe(); 
and all will work correctly.